# How can I return an empty IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, ienumerable

Hy guys!

My app is doing a query like this:

```
        public Order GetOrderByPerson(Order order, Person person)
        {
             return Repository.All()
                .Where( x => x.Order == order )
                .Where( y => y.envolvedPerson == person )
                .Single();
        };
```

And when there is no elements, it returns an error:

> Sequence contains no elements

Is ok to return null, how can I prevent this error?

Tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
return Repository.All()
                .Where( x => x.Order == order )
                .Where( y => y.envolvedPerson == person )
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

and check if its null in the calling method

Answer (score 2):

You can check for !Respository.Any() to check for Enumerable Null or Count is Zero.